# No HiDPI scaling in windowed mode on remote desktop session between two Windows 11 computers

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, high-dpi

I connect via built-in RDP from Win11 with 125% scaling to another Win11 machine with 200% (though that shouldn't matter).

If I set connection to fullscreen then remote session adopts 125% scaling but for any windowed mode there is no scaling, i.e. it reverts to 100%.

Scaling options not available within RDP session and RDP client has no options to control it.

Both Win11 are up-to-date.

I do not have `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\IgnoreClientDesktopScaleFactor` registry entry as per this [kb](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/remoteapp-window-is-too-large-or-too-small-when-you-use-rdp-to-run-a-remoteapp-application-in-windows-server-2012-r2-c8e721c7-bea2-5560-866f-b152d90af83a).

Is this expected or a bug?